# How to get SELECT values and COUNT value with JPA GROUP BY?

Tags: jpa

If my entity is get as a Man, it have name, id  properties, with JPA how I get retrieve result like this query,

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT m.name AS name, COUNT(m) AS total FROM Man AS m GROUP BY m.name ORDER BY m.name ASC");
```

Is there any way to use  `org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper` with JPA?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When you execute this query, instead of getting directly a list of objects like usual, you'll retrieve a list of `Object[]`.

For each array you retrieve, the first element will be the name of the row, the second the count.

I don't think you can use a `RowMapper` with JPA. `RowMapper` comes from Spring, which is not the same framework as JPA. Maybe some JPA implementation allow this, but I don't think it is wise to do so.

Edit - Code Example:

```
List<Object[]> results = entityManager
        .createQuery("SELECT m.name AS name, COUNT(m) AS total FROM Man AS m GROUP BY m.name ORDER BY m.name ASC");
        .getResultList();
for (Object[] result : results) {
    String name = (String) result[0];
    int count = ((Number) result[1]).intValue();
}
```

Comment: Hi Barousse! Thanks a lot for your feed back. If you have, can you please put some sample code way that can retrieve data as list of "Object[]", because yet I have not any idea how I match these result to some object. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Barousse! Many thanks for your great feed back, it works fine :), have a nice time!

Comment: It's not a SQL query. It's a JPQL query.