# JPQL return list of numbers in NamedQuery (with group by)

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, openjpa

I would like to create a query that returns all roomIds of a Entity Client that are stored in the database. roomId is an attribute in the Client entity.

I would like to use a type safe construct like this:

```
TypedQuery<Set<Long>> q = em.createNamedQuery("getRoomIdsByServer", Set.class);
q.setAttribute("server",server);
```

however this will create a compilation error.

The NamedQuery might look something like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getRoomIdsByServer", query = "SELECT c.room_id FROM Client c WHERE c.server = :server GROUP BY c.room_id")
```

However this seems to be beyond the scope of JPQL.
We are using openJPA (version 2.2.1)

There is one solution to solve this problem *without* using a typed query, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6956037/1448704 
But I would like to use a typed query to prevent those nasty cast operations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to cast `<long>` in your TypedQuery.See this;

```
    TypedQuery<Set> q = em.createNamedQuery("getRoomIdsByServer", Set.class);
    q.setAttribute("server",server);
```

or you can use like this;

```
    public List<String> getAllRoomIds(String server) {
          return em.createNamedQuery("getRoomIdsByServer", Set.class).setParameter("server", server).getResultList();
     }
```

Comment: unfortunatelly there is a need to cast then. The interface defines the return type of the query as "List<Long>". TypedQuery<List> q = em.createNamedQuery("getRoomsIdsByServer", List.class); cannot be cast to List<Long>! Error will be: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List> to List<Long>, same for TypedQuery<Set>, it cannot be cast to List<Long>.

Comment: another issue is that the list won't be "empty" if there is no roomId found, it will return a List with one entry, and the entry will be null. Cause that is exactly the result of the query, "group by" will _always_ return a record, even if the table is empty.