# How to get SELECT values and COUNT value with JPA GROUP BY

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I can not see how can I can use a JPA Query like this...

> @Query(value = "select statusupdateid, count(*) from comments group by statusupdateid", nativeQuery = true)
>       public

It should give a StatusUpdate id and the count...

I do not know whether to use a HashMap or what.... but the object solution from [How to get SELECT values and COUNT value with JPA GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955993/how-to-get-select-values-and-count-value-with-jpa-group-by) does not look like an elegant solution and my HashMap does not work

`public HashMap<StatusUpdate, Long> topComments();`

Thanks

Comment: are you using Spring Data ?

Comment: Yes. The question has to do more what would you use to iterate through those (Object, long) pairs of data. Thanks Bhushan

Answer (score 3):

You can use it like, you need a class with hold statusupdateid,statusupdateid

with parametrized constructor :

```
    class Data {
    //please modify datatype as per your structure
     long statusupdateid;
     long count
    public(long statusupdateid, long count)
    this.statusupdateid=statusupdateid;
    this.count =count;
    }
```

Now your query will:

```
@Query(value = "select statusupdateid, count(*) from comments group by statusupdateid", nativeQuery = true) 
public List<Data> findStatusupdateidAndCount();
```

Now it will return the list of `Data` which have  statusupdateid and it count

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value = "select statusupdateid as statusupdateid , count(*) as count from comments group by statusupdateid")
public List<Map<String,Object>> find();
```

or

```
@Query(value = "select statusupdateid as statusupdateid , count(*) as count from comments group by statusupdateid")
public Page<Map<String,Object>> find(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite old post but one solution will be using [BIN_TO_UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_bin-to-uuid)

```
@Query(value = "select BIN_TO_UUID(statusupdateid), count(*) from comments group by statusupdateid", nativeQuery = true) 
public List<String> findStatusupdateidAndCount();
```